# Vieta's Formula and Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, cubics

The following below is a question i was asked. The question left me stunned as i was unable to solve it. The question is as follows:

If $A$,$B$ and $C$ are roots of the cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ such that $3c=5a+b+d$ Then the value of $$\frac{(A+B+C)^2(1+A+B+C)-(A^3+B^3+C^3)+ABC(A+B+C+3)}{(A+B+C)}$$ will be:

(a) 3
(b) 5
(c) A^2+3AB - 2
(d) 3ABC-5

Based on my current understanding, i am aware of Vieta's formula for cubics and its results. I would appreciate any help in solving this problem with an explanation.

Comment: $3x^3+5x$ satisfies the condition, and its roots are easy to find, you could check which of the four choices works.

Comment: Thats a pretty good observation. But in this case, roots obtained are irrational and solving and computing using irrational numbers get confusing and complicated. But, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: The roots are $0$ and $\pm i\sqrt{5/3}$. The sum of the roots is zero, also the product of the three roots, also the sum of their cubes. That's not so complicated. (Unfortunately, the expression we're asked to evaluate then takes the form $0/0$, which is not much help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)(x+(1/3))=x^3-(8/3)x^2+x+(2/3)$ satisfies the hypotheses, and the expression in the question evaluates to $5$, so the answer is (b).

Simpler is the polynomial $x^3-5x^2$ with roots $0,0,5$ and the expression evaluating to $5$.

Comment: One other simple polynomial that works is $x^3-x^2+x-1$ with roots $1, \pm i$. $\,$ (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding and simplifying:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\delta 
& := \frac{(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+1)-\left(\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3\right)+\alpha\,\beta\,\gamma\,(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+3)}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma} \\
& = (\alpha+\beta+\gamma) + 3(\alpha\,\beta+\alpha\,\gamma+\beta\,\gamma) + (\alpha\,\beta\,\gamma) \\
& = -b/a+3\,c/a-d/a \\
& = -b/a+(5\,a+b+d)/a-d/a \\
& = 5
\end{aligned}
$$

hence the correct option is **b**.